# Android custom container (hexagonal) withe adapter

Tags: java, android, layout, view, containers

I want to create a custom android container. Where I can easily add and remove objects. The container should place objects inside hexagons. The order in which objects places is really important and shown in the image below. Objects in this adapter are click-able ImageViews (circular). 
It is even possible to make something like this for Android?

[image: Hexagon-Circle]

I know that there were similar questions like mine, but there are not even close to what I want to achieve.

Probably more and more people where looking for more custom containers like that one I'm trying to make. Not the standard one like in other apps: GridsView, ListView, etc.

**What I've already made**

I decided to use *RecyclerView* and custom *RecyclerView.LayoutManagers*. Also write an algorithm to define a position of ImageViews. Unfortunately I'am not familiar with LayoutManager and not sure how should I define places using it Interface.

[RecyclerView](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview#layoutmanagers)

Here is algorithm:

```
List<Object> list; 
int nuberOfElements = list.size();
int layerNr = 0;
int radius = 0;
int angle = 0;

//handle first middel element postion(0,0)
nuberOfPlaceElements --;
radius += r;

for(layerNr=1; nuberOfElements > 0; layerNr ++){
    for(int elementInLayer = 0; elementInLayer < layerNr * 6; elemnetInLayer ++){ 
        //layerNr *6 -> define how many elements in layer

        angle += 360/layerNr * 6
        //handle the postion of elemnts in Layer

        nuberOfElements--;
    }
    radius += r;
    angle = 0;
}
```

[image: Hexagon-Order]

Answer (score 1):

best solution is to create a custom layout (http://lucasr.org/2014/05/12/custom-layouts-on-android/) but that's also the most expensive way (cost on time to implement)...

alternative you can create a custom view and draw images directly there (http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)

all you ever want to know about hex-maps: http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/

why is layout better than a custom drawing view? it can be packed in a library and used for any other application whereas a custom drawing view is rather bound to the application...

Comment: Thx :) I will look at that solution. 
It's hard to add adapter to customView/customDrawing so I can easily remove, add items?

Comment: About custom drawing view. It's possible to draw ImageViews? For example set in List?

Comment: you can create a view anytime... and once created it's also quite simple to draw that view... and even though you can provide a layout model(not a real subclass of view/viewgroup, just a plain pojo model) wich determes, where to draw your imageViews (even though its very easy to draw a image directly)

Answer (score 1):

you can check this library which does exactly what you are asking for 
https://github.com/xresco/Hexagon-Recyclerview

It's super simple to use. 
Instead of using the default recyclerview (or listview) just use

`<com.abed.hexagonrecyclerview.view.HexagonRecyclerView   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/rvItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:items_count_in_row="3"
        app:items_horizontal_spacing="20dp"
        app:items_vertical_spacing="20dp"
        app:orientation="horizontal" />`

you can customize it using the following four parameters:

app:items_count_in_row
app:items_horizontal_spacing
app:items_vertical_spacing
app:orientation